# Output caching of API controllers in ASP.NET 5

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, http-caching

Am I correct that in ASP.NET 5 `ResponseCacheAttribute` has replaced [`OutputCacheAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) used in previous ASP.NET MVC releases? Can it be used to cache responses of API controllers? If not, what do Microsoft offer instead? I tried two free solution for WebAPI2 but was not impressed at all.

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET 5, you shouldn't have any `ApiController` types anymore. You should just have `Controller` types.  `ResponseCacheAttribute` works on `Controller` action methods.  One of the goals of ASP.NET 5 was to unify MVC's `Controller` and WebAPI's `ApiController`.

Comment: That would be great! But why is `ResponseCacheAttribute ` located in `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` namespace then (I'm looking at github)?

Comment: ResponseCache is not a replacement for OutputCache. ResponseCache does not cache the output in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to use the `ResponseCacheAttribute`.

Because there is no difference between a Web Api `Controller` and an MVC `Controller`, you will be able to use the same attributes for both.  This will apply whether it is the `ResponseCacheAttribute`, `AuthorizeAttribute`, `RouteAttribute`, or any others.